# OAuth Response_type = 'Code'

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

During OAuth Authenticaion , I have seen the code using "Response_type = 'Code'" 
in Url Parameters , can anyone explain what does this "code" mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Please find this [link](https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/) describing different values for response types.  `response_type=code` - Indicates that your server expects to receive an authorization code

Answer (score 0):

Authorization code the consumer must use to obtain the access and refresh tokens.